# How/should I suggest an in person interview after having a video interview while abroad

Tags: interviewing, email, follow-up, travel

I had video interview 2 months ago while abroad and followed up with an email after a month;  they were still in the interview process. Fast forward to now, I'm back in the states and was thinking by following up with suggesting an in-person interview. Not sure if I should and if so not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Vote cast as a duplicate. There's an additional factor here but the core problem about following up on an application remains the same and isn't notably affected by the fact that you're back in the country.

Comment: Fine to follow up saying "Just wanted to check on the status of my application. I am now back from abroad and am available to meet in person if you would like."

Answer (score 1):

While I think that you could contact them again to say that you are physically available again, I don't think that you should propose a face-to-face interview.

You don't have all the details of the hiring process. Maybe they don't need another interview. Maybe they are waiting  for some budget, maybe they already have someone, etc.

While you can be active to arrange details, the decision to have an interview or not lies with the hiring company. Not the candidate.

Answer (score 1):

If after two months and multiple contacts they haven't gotten back to you, it's reasonable to assume they're not interested. Expend your energies in other directions.